What's the name of the romance movie where the girl is a sailor and her boat capsizes?
I've been searching through pages and pages of movie titles and can't figure out the name of a specific movie I watched a while back. 
If someone can help I would appreciate it a lot.
The movie is about a boy who likes a girl but he's a jock and she's a loner or something like that. He's a drinker and sticks up for the girl when his douchebag friends make fun of her (he punches them in a bar).
On a boat/dock setting he draws a picture of her boat and they start to fall in love. She asks if she can have the picture of her boat he drew. I think he lives on his own and has a bunch of boat related articles or something in his house. 
She's a sailor and ends up taking her boat out in the storm, her boat capsizes in the middle of no where and everyone  thinks she is dead but the boy knows she's alive so they go search for her and she's found almost dead on a bunch of rocks but his body heat kept her alive. At the end of the movie they fall in love and go for a ride on her fixed up boat. 
I watched it sometime during the year of 2016. I'm not sure when it was released. Its in English and I live in America so I'm assuming it's an American movie. It wasn't an older type movie. It was in color. 

Welcome to the community. Answering the following questions will help us to respond. Any other plot details? What year did you see it? What was the language? Can you estimate the year and country of production? I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

You’re probably thinking of Charlie St. Cloud with Zac Efron and Amanda Crew.

Wikipedia:

Charlie St. Cloud is a 2010 American drama film based on Ben Sherwood's best-selling novel, The Death and Life of Charlie St. Cloud published in 2004 by Bantam Books. The film is directed by Burr Steers and stars Zac Efron and Amanda Crew. The story is of Charlie St. Cloud's choice between keeping a promise he made to his brother, who died in a car accident, or going after the girl he loves. In some markets the film used the complete title of the book.

